# Error post unlocking Jenkins: ERROR: : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I am getting Jenkins erorr: An error occurred during installation: ERROR: : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1) when first time opening http://localhost:8080 on chrome post- Jenkins(2.249.2 version) installation.

steps followed:

1. Browse to http://localhost:8080 (or whichever port you configured for Jenkins when installing it) and wait until the Unlock Jenkins page appears
2. copy administrator password from /Jenkins.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword and paste it to Administrator password text field
3. click continue button.

Getting error as "An error occurred during installation: ERROR: : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1)"

Don't know how to fix this error. I installed Jenkins 2.249.2 version.

Pls, find attached screenshot.[Jenkins Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgCOG.png)

Comment: That usually means you have invalid ASCII characters in your pasted password.  Try copying the password from the command line by `cat`ing it out first.

Comment: Thanks, i uninstalled Jenkins and deleted the installed folder Jenkins.jenkins and Jenkinswar manually. Reinstalled Jenkins and copying pw from the command line using cat ing and that worked.